# Read value of external application's status bar

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I am programming an add-on application for a meteorological data viewing application. I need to read the application's status bar. I know it will probably mean calling some Win32 code, but I found nothing in online research.

The status bar looks like this.
[image: status bar example]

Comment: Out of curiosity, can the down voter please explain the fault in my question?

Comment: Since you're using C#, you can use the classes in the System.Windows.Automation namespace. No need to get your hands dirty with Win32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want is `GetWindowText`, but you have to pass it the HWnd of the status bar panel you want to read. Retrieving that is nearly impossible, but not impossible.

You can use `EnumWindows` and `EnumChildWindows` to *search* through the application and find the text.

Comment: I did a little research on your suggestion, and after looking at my needs, this looks like the solution. Thanks, I'll mark it as my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a crazy solution, but off the top of my head, read through the memory that the program has allocated and search for the address that holds the progress bar float value.

You can probably use something like Cheat Engine to get the address and write some ASM to get it to work.

Comment: If I'm correct, where something is in memory can't be guaranteed, that's why pointer are used in C/C++.